# I cannot call the method of fragment at Activity because objects of fragment is constructed by the newInstance method

Tags: java, android

I'd like to make a MediaPlayer stop in fragment when the button in activity is pressed. 
I made the stopMediaPlayer() method in the fragment. and I tried to call the stopMediaPlayer() at onClick(View view) method in Activity.

But in my case, 
the objects of fragment is constructed using newInstance.
And those are added the FragmentAdater class that extends FragmentPagerAdapter class. like below.
it means I have no instance of the fragment that I can call the method directly from Activity.
I have to call the method using the Adapter instance because it has the FragmentManager.

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    fragmentArrayList.add(fragment);
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragmentArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentArrayList.size();
}
```

------------------Activity below-------------------------------------

```
WholeGuideFragment wholeGuideFragment = new WholeGuideFragment();
Part1QuestionFragment part1QuestionFragment = new Part1QuestionFragment();
Part2QuestionFragment part2QuestionFragment = new Part2QuestionFragment();
Part3QuestionFragment part3QuestionFragment = new Part3QuestionFragment();
Part4QuestionFragment part4QuestionFragment = new Part4QuestionFragment();
Part5QuestionImageFragment part5QuestionImageFragment = new Part5QuestionImageFragment();
Part5QuestionStringFragment part5QuestionStringFragment = new Part5QuestionStringFragment();
Part6QuestionFragment part6QuestionFragment = new Part6QuestionFragment();
StopButton stopButton = StopButton.getStopButton();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_part1);
    setFragmentAdapter();
    initView();
    setSession();
    checkPermission();
    //audio record 묻기

    Log.d("aaa", "Acitivity onCreate");
}

private void setFragmentAdapter() {
    fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(wholeGuideFragment);
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(PartGuideFragment.newInstance(1, this));
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(part1QuestionFragment);
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(PartGuideFragment.newInstance(2, this));
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(part2QuestionFragment);
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(PartGuideFragment.newInstance(3, this));
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(part3QuestionFragment);
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(PartGuideFragment.newInstance(4, this));
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(part4QuestionFragment);
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(PartGuideFragment.newInstance(5, this));
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(part5QuestionImageFragment);
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(part5QuestionStringFragment);
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(PartGuideFragment.newInstance(6, this));
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(part6QuestionFragment);
}
private void initView() {
    isStopped = false;
    next_btn = findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
    back_btn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
    play_pause_button = findViewById(R.id.play_pause_button);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
    viewPager.beginFakeDrag();
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
    next_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    back_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    play_pause_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    play_pause_button.setSelected(true);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int button_id = view.getId();
    position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    switch (button_id) {
        case R.id.next_btn:
            setNext(position);
            break;
        case R.id.back_btn:
            setBefore(position);
            break;
        case R.id.play_pause_button:
            if (play_pause_button.isSelected()) {
                fragmentPlayStop(position, play_pause_button.isSelected());
                stopButton.setStopButtonClicked(false);
                play_pause_button.setSelected(false);
            } else {
                fragmentPlayStop(position, play_pause_button.isSelected());
                stoppedPageNum = position;
                savedStoppedQ_num(position);
                stopButton.setStopButtonClicked(true);
                play_pause_button.setSelected(true);
            }
            //play_pause_button is selector:true=play_button,false=pause
            //stopButton is a Singleton class can share the boolean value to other fragments whether the activity stop button is pressed or not
            //stoppedPageNum and savedStoppedQ_num method is to compare the page whether the user pressed the button at the same fragment or not.
            //timer 초기화.
            break;
    }
}
public void fragmentPlayStop(int stop_play_position, boolean b) {
    if (b == true) {
        stoppedPageNum = checkStopAndCurrentPage(stop_play_position);
        fragmentonResume(stoppedPageNum);
    } else {
        fragmentonPause(stop_play_position);
    }
}
private void fragmentonPause(int stop_play_position) {
    switch (stop_play_position) {
        case 0:
            wholeGuideFragment.onPause();
            break;
        case 1:
            //mp stop
            break;
        case 2:
            part1QuestionFragment.stopMediaPlayer();
            part1QuestionFragment.stopTimer();
            break;
        case 3:
            //Guide fragment에서 mediaplayer어떻게 스탑할건지 생각하기
            //mp stop
            break;
        case 4:   break;
        case 5:
            //Guide fragment에서 mediaplayer어떻게 스탑할건지 생각하기
            //mp stop
            break;
        case 6:
            //mp, timer stop
            break;
        case 7:
            //Guide fragment에서 mediaplayer어떻게 스탑할건지 생각하기
            //인터페이스로 mpstop 이나 onPause호출하기
            break;
        case 8:
            //mp, timer stop
            break;
        case 9:
            //Guide fragment에서 mediaplayer어떻게 스탑할건지 생각하기
            //mp stop
            break;
        case 10:
            //mp stop
            break;
        case 11:
            //mp, timer stop
            break;
        case 12:
            //Guide fragment에서 mediaplayer어떻게 스탑할건지 생각하기
            //mp stop
            break;
        case 13:
            //mp, timer stop
            break;
    }
}
```

Problem is here.
I cannot call the method of fragment like below because of the objects through the newInstance method. in case of 1,3,5,7,9,12 I have to call the method stopMediaPlayer();

```
(PartGuideFragment)fragmentAdapter.getItem(9).stopMediaPlayer();
```

I've tried ,but I can only call the override method like onPause,onStop...

+refer to below FragmentClass -> "PartGuideFragment"

```
public static PartGuideFragment newInstance(int part, GuideCompleteListener guideCompleteListener) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("part", part);
    PartGuideFragment fragment = new PartGuideFragment();
    fragment.guideCompleteListener = guideCompleteListener;
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_part1_guide, container, false);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.guide_txt);
    part = getArguments().getInt("part");
    setGuideString();
    return view;
}

private void setGuideString() {
    switch (part){
        case 1:
            str = guidData.getPart1Guide();
            break;
        case 2:
            str = guidData.getPart2Guide();
            break;
        case 3:
            str = guidData.getPart3Guide();
            break;
        case 4:
            str = guidData.getPart4Guide();
            break;
        case 5:
            str = guidData.getPart5Guide();
            break;
        case 6:
            str = guidData.getPart6Guide();
            break;
    }
    Markwon.setMarkdown(textView, str);
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        if(mediaPlayer == null){
            setMediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }else{
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }else{
        if(mediaPlayer == null){
            setMediaPlayer();
        }else{
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}

private void setMediaPlayer() {
    switch (part) {
        case 1:
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.part1_direction);
            break;
        case 2:
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.part2_direction);
            break;
        case 3:
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.part3_direction);
            break;
        case 4:
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.part4_direction);
            break;
        case 5:
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.part5_direction);
            break;
        case 6:
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.part6_direction);
            break;
    }
}

public void stopMediaPlayer(){
    if(mediaPlayer!= null){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}

public void playMediPalyer(){
    if(mediaPlayer!= null){
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }else{
        setMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked for many times. There are many ways to communicate between Activity/Fragment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Comment: RxBus, EventBus, GreenDao, LocalBroadcastReceiver

Answer (score 0):

You just did a wrong cast. Try this one

```
((PartGuideFragment)fragmentAdapter.getItem(9)).stopMediaPlayer();
```

Comment: Casting a class and call its method is not a good approach because you couldn't ensure if that fragment is still visible/available to user. This might lead to null pointer exception or IllegalStateException or other unexpected errors.

Comment: @PhátPhát What is a problem? We could check if he is not a null and also instanceof some the special class.